# How can I check if the motherboard has been replaced?

Tags: motherboard

An authorized repair center said  they changed the motherboard of my iMac 27" but I have doubts since I can still experience the problem for what I had it *repaired*.

I was told on a forum that if the computer's SN was invisible or started differently in the About this Mac menu it meant that the MB had been replaced.
I'm seeing the same SN so it should mean that the MB was not replaced, but on the phone the repair guy said this method is wrong.

What do you say ?

Comment: @user2113 So, did they change it?

Answer (score 3):

The MAC address is linked to the logic board. So, if the logic board has been changed, MAC address will have changed too.
I've been told this by a Genius et Genius Bar when he said they need to change my logic board and asked if my router was checking MAC address for allowing net access, as I will then have to reconfigure it.
It also seems to be backed-up by [this technical note](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn/tn1103.html) (look for first occurrence of "logic board").

Edit: For your previous MAC addresses (ethernet and wifi and bluetooth, as I suppose they all change on a logic board exchange), you will find them on your computer's box, if you still have it (but it seems to be the case:)). These are the Ethernet ID, Airport ID and Bluetooh ID. You can then check in System Profiler to get the current ones.

Comment: hm ok, but how do I get the previous MAC address ? on the cardboard box there's only the Ethernet ID and Airport ID.

Comment: The Ethernet ID is the MAC address, as far as I know.

Comment: Ethernet ID is the MAC address of your Ethernet card and Airport ID is the MAC address of your Wifi card.

Comment: Edited my answer